# How to configure RESTEasy Application at root path ("/")

Tags: servlets, jakarta-ee, jax-rs, wildfly, resteasy

I use WildFly 11. I have following `@ApplicationPath` declaration:

```
@ApplicationPath("/")
public class JaxrsConfiguration extends Application {}
```

I have to use root path, but sadly in this configuration RESTEasy matches all requests. Looking at source code at https://github.com/resteasy/Resteasy/blob/master/resteasy-servlet-initializer/src/main/java/org/jboss/resteasy/plugins/servlet/ResteasyServletInitializer.java I found that in my case `HttpServlet30Dispatcher` is registered at `/*` which is terrible case. Is it possible to register RESTEasy servlet on `"/"` or as filter (**while still having automatic resource scanning**)?

Comment: Your goal is to register RESTEasy on "/" but, for example, not "/somepath" ?